# Codeigniter 404 page throwing error when loading a spark library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m running into a problem tonight that i just can’t figure out. I’m loading the spark for the [Carabiner Asset Library](http://getsparks.org/packages/carabiner/versions/HEAD/show)

```
$this->load->spark('carabiner/1.5.4', array('library' => 'carabiner'));
```

I’m running into an error/ no error loading the spark in these senarios:

**default_controller/foo** <- foo method does not exist, 404 loads fine

**other_controller/bar** <- bar is a method in other_controller, method load fine

**other_controller/wakawaka** -> wakawaka does not exist, Message: Undefined property: 
Error::$carabiner

```
$this->carabiner->config($carabiner_config);
```

is the line php/codeigniter is complaining about

Carabiner is being loaded in a MY_controller where default_controller and other_controller both extend MY_controller

I commented out the config line above and got the same error on the next spark i had to load and call, Template.

Any idea what’s going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you load the carabiner in MY_Controller constructor make sure you call the parent constructor in controllers that extend it.